# Ubuntu on Advent Torino X700

Tags: system-installation, hardware, compatibility

I am intested in buying the Advent Torino X700. I do not like windows 8 and I already use Ubuntu so I would want to install Ubuntu desktop onto it. I noticed that this computer is not on the list of certified hardware, no advent computers are. Does this mean ubuntu won't work on it? Will I be able to put Ubuntu on it? If so, how? Just by buying a disk and booting off of the disk? Or is my hardware not supported? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that this computer is not on the list of certified hardware, no advent computers are. Does this mean ubuntu won't work on it?

Means Advent has not taken the time to go through Ubuntu certification.

> Will I be able to put Ubuntu on it? If so, how? Just by buying a disk and booting off of the disk? Or is my hardware not supported? Thanks!

Either (1) Call Advent and ask them, or

(2) Prepare a LiveUSB (following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) which begin with Installing Ubuntu in UEFI Mode) and take it to the store which displays your machine of choice. Ask the clerk there to allow you to test. Insert the LiveUSB and try Ubuntu without installing. If it boots and shows you the Ubuntu graphical user interface, it will work just fine for you.